# Detect the time of event from the video file

Tags: python, opencv

[image]I am new to OpenCV. I am trying to detect the exact point of event from the video file. How Can I do that? This is how my program load the video file and apply contour to locate the event.

```
ret, frame=cap.read()
frame[frame<=thresholds]=0
print("DEBUG: line 67: ", len(frame))
mask = object_detector.apply(frame)
_, mask  = cv2.threshold(mask,254,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)        #mask the backgroubd to the color ratio of 255 for complete black color
contours,_ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame,mask=mask)
for cnt in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    if area>100:    #detect for the flashes above 1000pixel
        cv2.drawContours(frame, [cnt], -1, (0,255,0),2) 
key = cv2.waitKey(5)
if key =='27':
    break
cv2.imshow("Frame",frame)
cv2.imshow("Mask",mask)
cv2.imshow("res", res)'''
```

Comment: cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC) if think after reading the frame. But I dont know how reliable that is in different backends.

Comment: Thank You for reply. It didn't helped me detect the time of event. I am trying to detect the light flash to be exact. I have included the exact event in the question.

Comment: so it is not about detecting the time, but detecting the event? Just use findContours on that image and if there is a contour with some minimum or known cv2.contourArea accept it.

Comment: The issue was not solved, could you please help me out. I tried using findContour but it doesn't help me find the time of event.

Comment: I dont understand your requirements. You read a video frame by frame and once you detect the event (I dont understand what you mean by event, btw.) you can use cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC) to read the current time.

Comment: The event is the light flash that you see in the image above. The flash is seen randomly throughout the video. I am trying to detect the time (in second) when the flash was seen from the time of start of video file.

Comment: Are you able to detect for a single image, whether there is the light flash present in that image or not?

Comment: No, I tried using, for each frame, 'contours, hierarchy= cv2.findContours(frame, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)' but it shows an error